# Where is _TRACE macro defined in GNU?

Tags: c, gcc, gcc-warning

Where is _TRACE macro defined? What's the purpose of it? Does it trace the stack and lets you know when your app crash?

Comment: Where did you find it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want you can define it compile time using below command

```
make CFLAGS=-D_TRACE
```

Comment: What does it do? It gives you the stack trace so you can track back.

Comment: `TRACE` usually gives so many debug logs so you can easily debug. Other way to track back is to use `GDB`.

Comment: Thanks. Can you point me a link where this is defined in gcc?

Comment: Are you talking about `GDB`? sorry for late reply due to weekend. J